# how to change button color dynamically?

Tags: android, android-button

In my application i created dynamic buttons. Now i want to change the button background color and button text color whenever the button are clicked. I wrote the code for this.  My problem is when I clicked the button; the button changed background color. After that I click another button. I need to change the previous button to the previous state(only present click button need to change the color, remaining are need to in previous state)can anyone please help me.

mycode:

```
 try {
                    JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        final JSONObject jsonobj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                        if (!plantype.contains(jsonobj.getString("RCType"))) {
                            plantype.add(jsonobj.getString("RCType"));///butoon creation
                           // Log.e("TAG_BUTTONSSSSSS",""+plantype);


                             btn = new Button(getActivity());
                            btn.setTag(jsonobj.getString("PlanType"));

                            btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            btn.setText(jsonobj.getString("PlanType"));
                            btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rechargebtn);

                            btns_layout.addView(btn);
                            btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {


                                    String plan = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
                                    int index = plantype.indexOf(plan);

                                    // Log.v("TAG_INDEX",""+plan);
                                    Plans(index);
                                    Log.v("TAG_TAG", "" + ((Button) v).getTag());
                                    Log.v("TAG_TAG", "" + ((Button) v).getText());
                                    if (((Button) v).getTag().equals(((Button) v).getText())) {

                                        ((Button) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                        ((Button) v).setTextColor(Color.RED);


                                    } else{
                                        try {
                                            if (!((Button) v).getTag().equals(jsonobj.getString("PlanType"))) {
                                                ((Button) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                                                ((Button) v).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                }
                                }
                            });

                        }


                    }
```

Comment: please any one help me out

Comment: you must create override onClick in your activity. use switch case default to change your button back again

Comment: buttons can be only in 2 states right? clicked color and non-clicked color?define a constant instead and check if in which state button is in

Comment: @diva yes clicked color and non clicked color. please tell me how to do this. i tried but failed diva. please help me out.

Comment: could you please any one help me

Comment: what do you want? change color after user release the button or after another button clicked? you confuse me about *"clicked color and non clicked color"* and *"after that i clicked the another the button i need change the previous button to previous state"*

Comment: @Randyka Yudhistira yes change the button  color when user release the button. (clicked button is one color and remaining button are in one color)please help me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define colors in color.xml

```
color = ((ColorDrawable)button.getBackground()).getColor();

if( R.color.white==color)
{
button.setBackgroundColor(R.color.blue);
}else
{
button.setBackgroundColor(R.color.whit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/red"></item>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue"></item>
<item  android:drawable="@color/white"></item>
</selector>
```

and then use in your activity

```
  btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector);
```

Comment: in button onclick i will write this line na?

Comment: oncreate write this line

Answer (score 0):

1 . Make this selector xml into drawable folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
            <solid android:color="#D4A017" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#D4A017" />
        </shape></item>
    <item><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#ef5829" android:startColor="#ef5829" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ef5829" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

2. Next you have to set this selector as background to button like this :

   android:background = "@drawabale/selector_file_name"

That's it.

Comment: set this selector in button onclick ?

Comment: No, you just set this in layout xml file and when you pressed on button it will work.

Comment: no button in xml. dynamic button declaration in class file

Comment: and please let me know if it worked or not or there any error occurred.

Comment: Color is changed . but is not constant. I need the color to be constant untill  i click the another button it need to change. please help me.

Comment: check my new answer and get the logic

Answer (score 0):

For static button color you have to do ,

```
button1.setBackgroundcolor(any color);
button1.onclickmethod(){
//change button1 color
}

button2.setonclickmethod(){
//change button1 color to starting one
}
```

The answer is typed fast so just follow the logic only.

Comment: how i declare button 1 and button 2. dynamic buttons na

Comment: Button b1 = new Button(getActivity()); Button b2 = new Button(getActivity());

Comment: surender. i didnt get you. iT IS dynamic button creation. Then how i get button2

Comment: How many buttons do you want to create if it is fixed then you can try the above method , if it is not fixed then you have to make array.